# Compile Python 3.6 statically with OpenSSL

Tags: python, linux, openssl, static-linking

I'm trying to compile Python 3.6 on Linux statically with OpenSSL.

My build happens in a dockerfile, but essentially does:

```sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/task/build --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static"
$ make altinstall
```

With an update to `Modules/Setup.local` to make it look like:

```
*static*

# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
 -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
 -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

However, on the configure step, I get the error:

```
Step 9/14 : RUN ./configure --prefix=/task/build --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static"
     ---> Running in cb79ee47052b
    checking for git... found
    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for python3.6... no
    checking for python3... no
    checking for python... python
    checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
    checking for --with-universal-archs... no
    checking MACHDEP... linux
    checking for --without-gcc... no
    checking for --with-icc... no
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... no
    configure: error: in `/task/cpython':
    configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
The command '/bin/sh -c ./configure --prefix=/task/build --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static"' returned a non-zero code: 77
```

If I change the configure command to:

```sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/task/build --disable-shared
```

I get a compiled binary, but it isn't statically linked to OpenSSL.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

---

Build dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2017.03.1.20170812

ARG python_version=3.6.8

WORKDIR /task
COPY Modules-Setup.local /task/Modules-Setup.local

# Install requirements
RUN yum install -y \
  gcc \
  git \
  gzip \
  openssl-devel \
  tar \
  zlib \
  zlib-devel

# Get openssl and python source
RUN git clone https://github.com/python/cpython.git
WORKDIR /task/cpython
RUN git checkout tags/v${python_version}

# Configure the build
RUN ./configure --prefix=/task/build --disable-shared LDFLAGS="-static"

# Append modules setup with custom values
RUN cat /task/Modules-Setup.local >> /task/cpython/Modules/Setup.local
RUN cat /task/cpython/Modules/Setup.local

# Build
RUN make altinstall

# Zip the results
WORKDIR /task/build
RUN tar --create --gzip --file=/task/python-${python_version}.tar.gz \
  lib/ bin/
```

Comment: *configure* command is incorrect - try: `LDFLAGS="-static" ./configure --prefix=/task/build --disable-shared`. Could you detail what *statically linked to OpenSSL* means?

Comment: Statically linked means include the OpenSSL archive in the python lib bundle to me, lmk if that clarifies.

Comment: I thought so, 1st thing you'll need is the static *OpenSSL* libs. There's nothing (in terms of build flags, options) you can do on *Python* side if you don't have those. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725472/static-link-of-shared-library-function-in-gcc.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks.  I ultimately want a folder with everything I need to run python (with some linked modules available, like openssl) that I can copy to a machine and use immediately.  Should compiling (statically) those packages and linking them as described by jww below get me there?

Comment: This might be an *XY Problem*. There are tools (at least on *Win*) that collect anything needed for a piece of *Python* code to run (e.g. *py2exe*). You got the static linking wrong: it refers to the *python* executable: if static, it will have *~5MB*, otherwise, it will have *~10KB* (but you'll also have a *libpython3.6m.so* that the *.exe* depends on, and **that contains all the *Python* core functionality**). @jww explained it very well. Bottom line: if you want to statically link to something, that something should be (also) built for static linking.

Comment: I'm going to bombard you with info (although it's only remotely related to your problem):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664412/unable-to-build-a-working-fips-capable-openssl-on-hp-ux, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320993/how-to-enable-fips-mode-for-libcrypto-and-libssl-packaged-with-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493537/how-to-implement-fips-mode-and-fips-mode-set-in-python-3-6s-ssl-module.

Comment: Thanks Cristi - I want to do essentially what py2exe does, or what statifier did for linux.  I'm on linux (AWS AMI).  I'm now looking at this as a solution instead: https://github.com/marook/statifier/ . Thoughts?

Comment: On a 1st glance, *statifier*  is a 75 lines of *Python* code file. Not the way you're aiming to. And thanks, no more posts here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to compile Python 3.6 on Linux statically with OpenSSL.
>   ...
>
> ```
> # Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
> # socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
> SSL=/usr/local/ssl
> _ssl _ssl.c \
>  -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
>  -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
> ```

Change `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` to `-l:libssl.a` and `-l:libcrypto.a`:

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
  -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
  -L$(SSL)/lib -l:libssl.a -l:libcrypto.a
```

You can also use the full path to the archive:

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
  -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
  $(SSL)/lib/libssl.a $(SSL)/lib/libcrypto.a
```

Archives (`*.a`) are just a collection of object files (`*.o`), so you can use an archive wherever you use an object file.

Also see `-l:filename` in the [`ld(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> ***`--library=namespec`***
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
>   files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If
>   namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for
>   a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for
>   a file called libnamespec.a.

If you have other components in `/usr/local` you are using, then you might want to add `-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to your `LDFLAGS`. The `new-dtags` embeds a `RUNPATH` (as opposed to `RPATH`) in the ELF headers. `RUNPATH` can be overridden with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

---

> I get a compiled binary, but it isn't statically linked to OpenSSL.

The way to check is to use `ldd` with the paths you use at runtime. For example, here is from a local OpenSSL build on Fedora:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/openssl
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3cde6000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f043dc4e000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f043d9df000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f043d9c0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f043d7fa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f043dcc0000)
```

---

Here are a couple of related questions, but it does not look like they cover static linking with Python.

- [Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5937337/608639)
- [How do I compile Python 3.4 with custom OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23548188/608639)

---

And to be clear, `config.log` has the error but you did not show the relevant portion from it:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/task/cpython':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Static OpenSSL may (or may not) fix the problem.

Comment: Is there a way (similar to `ldd`) to discover the shared objects that my compiled binary will import during execution (not just at startup)?

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same issue and solved it by installing the static glibc libraries:

```
yum install glibc-static
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the python repository, where it has a list of modules and c filename that python need to compile python:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/51863b7d6ea183167da09fc6b3f2745a1aaa4ef5/Modules/Setup#LL232

Something like this:

```
*static*

# Modules that should always be present (POSIX and Windows):

#_asyncio _asynciomodule.c
#_bisect _bisectmodule.c
#_contextvars _contextvarsmodule.c
#_csv _csv.c
#_datetime _datetimemodule.c
#_decimal _decimal/_decimal.c
#_heapq _heapqmodule.c
#_json _json.c
#_lsprof _lsprof.c rotatingtree.c
#_multiprocessing -I$(srcdir)/Modules/_multiprocessing _multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c _multiprocessing/semaphore.c
#_opcode _opcode.c
#_pickle _pickle.c
#_queue _queuemodule.c
#_random _randommodule.c
#_socket socketmodule.c
#_statistics _statisticsmodule.c
...
```

Do an uncomment, and put it into 'Setup.local' file, then you are ready to go.

---

If you really don't know how to compile it, I have a dockerfile for you:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

ENV PYTHON_VER 3.10.4
ENV PYTHON_LIB_VER 3.10

RUN mkdir /build /package
WORKDIR /build

RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VER/Python-$PYTHON_VER.tgz && tar -xzf Python-$PYTHON_VER.tgz
WORKDIR Python-$PYTHON_VER

RUN apk add musl-dev 
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add linux-headers
RUN apk add bash

RUN apk add python3-dev py3-pip 
RUN apk add git vim wget make

RUN apk add openssl-dev
RUN apk add sqlite-dev
RUN apk add zlib-dev
RUN apk add bzip2-dev
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add util-linux-dev
RUN apk add xz-dev
RUN apk add libnsl-dev libtirpc-dev
RUN apk add gdbm-dev
RUN apk add tk-dev

RUN apk add ncurses-dev
RUN apk add readline-dev

# RUN python3 -m ensurepip
# RUN pip3 install readline

ADD Setup.local Modules/
ENV LDFLAGS "-static"
RUN ./configure LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc" CPPFLAGS="-static" --disable-shared --with-ensurepip=install --with-ssl --with-zlib --enable-nis --with-tirpc-include-dir=/usr/include/tirpc --with-gdbm
RUN make -j$(nproc) LDFLAGS="-static" LINKFORSHARED=" "

# RUN cp libpython$PYTHON_LIB_VER.a /usr/lib
# WORKDIR /build
# ENV LDFLAGS "-static -l:libpython3.10.a"


CMD sleep 999999999999
# Manually copy /build to host storage
```

Comment: I simply compiled a static version of python with all modules supported: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nR1owjXuzoxOw9lie5Js5JyCOI1xscBQ/view?usp=sharing