# OpenSSL FIPS_mode_set not working in Python cryptography library

Tags: python, c, compilation, openssl, fips

According to Python Cryptography library's documentation [1], it is possible to build a custom cryptography wheel with OpenSSL statically linked. I tried doing this with an OpenSSL installation built with FIPS object module and was able to successfully build the wheel but found out that it did not have FIPS functionality (unable to set FIPS_mode_set=1).

I have created a Dockerfile that can reproduce the same result. The Python code at the end are supposed to show "1" and "OpenSSL 1.0.2t-fips  10 Sep 2019" and but instead show "0" and "OpenSSL 1.0.2t  10 Sep 2019" (no `-fips` designation).

The thing that boggles my mind is that when I invoke `openssl version` CLI that I built, it correctly shows the version with the `-fips` suffix. Because, of this I'm guessing that I went wrong somewhere in building cryptography.

Appreciate any help here!

```
FROM centos

# Install build dependencies
RUN yum groupinstall -y  "Development Tools" && \
    yum install -y python-devel libffi-devel

# Install Python dependencies
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && \
    python get-pip.py && \
    pip install virtualenv setuptools wheel pip

# Build Fips object module
RUN curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-fips-2.0.16.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf openssl-fips-2.0.16.tar.gz && \
    cd openssl-fips-2.0.16 && \
    ./config && \
    make && \
    make install

# Build OpenSSL
RUN curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2t.tar.gz && \
    tar xvf openssl-1.0.2t.tar.gz && \
    cd /openssl-1.0.2t && \
    ./config fips no-shared -fPIC --prefix=/openssl-1.0.2t/openssl && \
    make depend && \
    make && \
    make install_sw

# Build cryptography
RUN CFLAGS="-I/openssl-1.0.2t/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L/openssl-1.0.2t/openssl/lib" pip wheel --no-cache --no-binary :all: cryptography && \
    pip install cryptography*.whl

# Test if fips is enabled
RUN python -c "\
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend;\
print backend._lib.FIPS_mode_set(1);\
print ''.join([backend._lib.OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT[i] for i in range(30)])"
```

[1] https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#static-wheels

**EDIT:** By adding `-DOPENSSL_FIPS` to the cryptography build, I was able to make output of `OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT` become `OpenSSL 1.0.2t-fips  10 Sep 20` but the output of FIPS_mode_set(1) is still 0.

**EDIT 2:** Using `ERR_get_error()` shows the following:

```
>>> print backend._lib.FIPS_mode_set(1)
0
>>> print backend._lib.ERR_get_error()
755413103
```

When I pop this into `openssl errstr` I get:

```
openssl errstr 755413103
error:755413103:lib(85):func(1043):reason(259)
```

According to some Google searches, this indicates that fingerprint doesn't match (`FIPS_R_FINGERPRINT_DOES_NOT_MATCH`). Not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: Actually, your error, was encountered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664412/unable-to-build-a-working-fips-capable-openssl-on-hp-ux :) . Try building a shared *OpenSSL* version: replace ***no-shared*** by ***shared***, and see if the problem still persists. Also, what does `OPPENSSL_FIPS=1 /openssl-1.0.2t/openssl/bin/openssl md5 /openssl-1.0.2t/openssl/bin/openssl md5` output?

Comment: What's your *Python* version (I assume it's *64bit*)?

Comment: @CristiFati Unfortunately "no-shared" won't work for me as I am aiming to have a static library created. Out of curiosity, however, I tried with no-shared but ended up getting other errors. The output of the md5 command you mentioned succeeded in my case (unfortunately). Regarding the Python version, I am indeed running 64bit.

Comment: I am preparing an answer, but it's taking a lot longer than I expected. If you didn't get the error you did something wrong (either at build or at runtime). About *Python*: I meant **version** (e.g. *3.7.3*), not architecture (*64ibit* - *AMD64*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. General

First of all, I want to mention that although I understand the reasons, I don't fully agree with *Cryptography*'s vision ([[Cryptography]: Installation - Static Wheels](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#static-wheels)). Shared libraries exist for decades and have proven their superiority. Not to mention that *Python* ships ***2*** (standard) modules (*_ssl* and *_hashlib*) that **dynamically** link to *OpenSSL* (whatever it's on the system). As a side note, on *Win*, the 2 *Python* modules also used to link statically to *OpenSSL*, but starting with *v**3.7***, they no longer do. Back to *Nix*: 2 *OpenSSL* versions are loaded into the same (*Python*) process. It doesn't seem to harm, but it looks funny. And as things are today (*191009*), there are a bunch of *.whl*s for *v2.7* and *v3.4*, but none for a fairly decent (*Python*) environment:

[image: Img0]

I remember a similar situation a while ago: besides the 2 standard modules, *M2Crypto* was also used. In that situation (we shipped *Python* entirely), the 2 specific (*FIPS* capable) *OpenSSL* (**dynamic**) *lib*s were shipped too, and all the *Python* modules linked to them. It worked on a variety of (**desktop**) environments (out of which many "exotic" ones):

- *CPU* architectures (*LE* / *BE*): *x86*, *AMD64*, *IA64*, *SPARC*, *PPC*, *zSeries*
- *OS*es (with multiple versions): *Win*, *Lnx* (*RH*, *CentOS*, *OEL*, *SuSE*, *Xen*, *Ubuntu*), *Solaris*, *AIX*, *HP-UX* (and as **personal exercise**, I added ***OSX***)

[[OpenSSL]: UserGuide-2.0.pdf - User Guide for the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) (referenced from [[OpenSSL]: FIPS-140](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips.html) in case the *URL* changes) contains all the details needed.

Before going further, here are some terms that I'm going to use throughout the post:

- *FOM* - *FIPS* object module (*fipscanister.o*)
- *FOME* - The executable (*ELF* (*PE* on *Win*)) that *FOM* was **linked in**. Bear in mind, that it can be either an executable *per se*, either an *.so* (*.dll*). Also, if it's included in a static lib (*.a*), it's not linked (just archived). As a side note, when *OpenSSL* is built shared, *FOME* is *libcrypto.so.**, while when built statically (like in this case), it's the executable that links with *libcrypto.a* (e.g. *openssl* executable)

*FOM* comes on top of *OpenSSL* (and probably other such cryptography providers, like *LibreSSL*, *WolfSSL*, ), and it's meant to strengthen security, (according to *NIST* standards), by restricting some features that otherwise would be available. One such feature example is the usage of ***md5*** hash, which is considered weak (I'm pretty sure that *sha1* will follow too, in the next version about to be released).
 Here's a (very simplified) version of what happens (at runtime):

1. *FIPS* mode on:

   1. Check whether the additional constraints are met:

      1. Yes: Proceed (with default functionality)
      2. No: Return with error
2. *FIPS* mode off:

   1. Fall back to default functionality

Part of ***#1.1.*** is the selftest. That consists of:

- Computing the *FOME* signature
- Comparing it to a value (that was also stored in *FOME*)

This happens to make sure (or drastically reduce the chances) that no one tampered (manually modifying, disassembling, ...) with *FOME*. To have a better understanding of the signature mechanism, let's dive into *FOME* build process:

1. All the *FOME* sources + *FOM* are compiled (into object files)
2. They are linked together (into *FOME*). This is when a normal build ends
3. The *FOME* signature is being computed

   1. Items from *#1.* + *fips_premain.o* are being linked into a (real, not *.dll*) executable (*FPD*)
   2. *FPD* is invoked against *FOME* (*#1.*). It reads *FOME*'s *.rodata* section and computes its *sha1* hash. Note that **it ignores a *41* bytes zone (punches a hole)** located at a specific address
4. *#3.1.* is repeated, but this time *fips_premain.o* was recompiled to also include the hash from previous step. Now it becomes clear the punched hole from previous step, it's the place where the signature goes: (length of *sha* hash (*40*) + *nul*). **This is the final *FOME***

Note: On *Win*, things happen just a bit differently.

I've managed to reproduce the problem. I'm going to start with the test script.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import cffi

from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend


def main(*argv):
    ffi = cffi.FFI()
    lib = backend._lib
    fmt = "OpenSSL version: {0:s}\nFIPS_mode(): {1:d}\nFIPS_mode_set(1): {2:d}\nFIPS_mode(): {3:d}"
    print(fmt.format(ffi.string(
        lib.OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT).decode(),
        lib.FIPS_mode(),lib.FIPS_mode_set(1), lib.FIPS_mode()
    ))
    err = lib.ERR_get_error()
    if err:
        err_fmt = "error:[{0:d}]:[{1:s}]:[{2:s}]:[{3:s}]"
        print(err_fmt.format(
            err,
            ffi.string(lib.ERR_lib_error_string(err)).decode(),
            ffi.string(lib.ERR_func_error_string(err)).decode(),
            ffi.string(lib.ERR_reason_error_string(err)).decode()
        ))
    else:
        print("Success !!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

### 2. Setup

I've already built *FOM* and a *FIPS* capable *OpenSSL* (similar to yours, but I customized their paths). The *${FIPSDIR}* variable was used when building both *FOM* and *OpenSSL*.

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435]> ~/sopr.sh
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [064bit-prompt]> uname -a
> Linux cfati-ubtu16x64-0 4.15.0-65-generic #74~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 18 09:51:44 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> [064bit-prompt]> cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCR
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
> [064bit-prompt]> gcc --version | grep gcc
> gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> echo ${FIPSDIR}
> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/zzz_Build/OpenSSL/int/openssl-fips-2.0.16
> [064bit-prompt]> tree ${FIPSDIR}
> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/zzz_Build/OpenSSL/int/openssl-fips-2.0.16
> ├── bin
> │   ├── fipsld
> │   └── fips_standalone_sha1
> ├── include
> │   └── openssl
> │       ├── aes.h
> │       ├── bn.h
> │       ├── buffer.h
> │       ├── cmac.h
> │       ├── crypto.h
> │       ├── des.h
> │       ├── des_old.h
> │       ├── dh.h
> │       ├── dsa.h
> │       ├── ebcdic.h
> │       ├── ecdh.h
> │       ├── ecdsa.h
> │       ├── ec.h
> │       ├── e_os2.h
> │       ├── evp.h
> │       ├── fips.h
> │       ├── fips_rand.h
> │       ├── fipssyms.h
> │       ├── hmac.h
> │       ├── modes.h
> │       ├── opensslconf.h
> │       ├── opensslv.h
> │       ├── ossl_typ.h
> │       ├── rsa.h
> │       ├── sha.h
> │       └── symhacks.h
> └── lib
>     ├── fipscanister.o
>     ├── fipscanister.o.sha1
>     ├── fips_premain.c
>     └── fips_premain.c.sha1
>
> 4 directories, 32 files
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> echo ${OPENSSL_DIR}
> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/openssl-1.0.2t-fips-2.0.16-static
> [064bit-prompt]> tree ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin ${OPENSSL_DIR}/lib
> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/openssl-1.0.2t-fips-2.0.16-static/bin
> ├── c_rehash
> └── openssl
> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/openssl-1.0.2t-fips-2.0.16-static/lib
> ├── engines
> ├── libcrypto.a
> ├── libssl.a
> └── pkgconfig
>     ├── libcrypto.pc
>     ├── libssl.pc
>     └── openssl.pc
>
> 2 directories, 7 files
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> ldd ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeec045000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f12c19c2000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f12c15f8000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f12c1bc6000)
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl version
> OpenSSL 1.0.2t-fips  10 Sep 2019
> [064bit-prompt]> ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl sha1 ./code00.py
> SHA1(./code00.py)= ff122260b025103dbc03316e3d3e26cd683e7a12
> [064bit-prompt]> ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl md5 ./code00.py
> MD5(./code00.py)= eac85e46734260c1bfcceb89d6a3bd32
> [064bit-prompt]> OPENSSL_FIPS=1 ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl sha1 ./code00.py
> SHA1(./code00.py)= ff122260b025103dbc03316e3d3e26cd683e7a12
> [064bit-prompt]> OPENSSL_FIPS=1 ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl md5 ./code00.py
> Error setting digest md5
> 140584610875032:error:060A80A3:digital envelope routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips:fips_md.c:180:
> ```

### 3. *Cryptography* module

> ```bash
> [064bit-prompt]> ls
> code00.py  cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
> [064bit-prompt]> mkdir build
> [064bit-prompt]> cd build
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> CFLAGS="-I${OPENSSL_DIR}/include -DOPENSSL_FIPS=1" LDFLAGS="-L${OPENSSL_DIR}/lib" python3 -m pip wheel --no-cache --no-binary :all: ../cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
> Processing /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
>   Installing build dependencies ... done
>   Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
>     Preparing wheel metadata ... done
> Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography==2.7)
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/e2/c518f2bc5805668803ebf0659628b0e9d77ca981308c7e9e5564b30b8337/asn1crypto-1.0.1.tar.gz (115kB)
>      |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 801kB/s
> Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 (from cryptography==2.7)
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/1a/ab8c62b5838722f29f3daffcc8d4bd61844aa9b5f437341cc890ceee483b/cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz (456kB)
>      |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 1.8MB/s
> Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from cryptography==2.7)
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/bf/4138e7bfb757de47d1f4b6994648ec67a51efe58fa907c1e11e350cddfca/six-1.12.0.tar.gz
> Collecting pycparser (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography==2.7)
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158kB)
>      |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 4.5MB/s
> Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography, asn1crypto, cffi, six, pycparser
>   Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517) ... done
>   Stored in directory: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build
>   Building wheel for asn1crypto (setup.py) ... done
>   Stored in directory: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build
>   Building wheel for cffi (setup.py) ... done
>   Stored in directory: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build
>   Building wheel for six (setup.py) ... done
>   Stored in directory: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build
>   Building wheel for pycparser (setup.py) ... done
>   Stored in directory: /home/cfati/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build
> Successfully built cryptography asn1crypto cffi six pycparser
> WARNING: You are using pip version 19.1.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> ls
> asn1crypto-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl        cryptography-2.7-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl  six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> cffi-1.12.3-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl  pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> for f in $(ls *.whl); do unzip ${f} > /dev/null; done
> [064bit-prompt]> ls
> asn1crypto                         cffi-1.12.3-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl        cryptography-2.7-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl  pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> asn1crypto-1.0.1.dist-info         cffi-1.12.3.dist-info                          cryptography-2.7.dist-info                    six-1.12.0.dist-info
> asn1crypto-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl  _cffi_backend.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  pycparser                                     six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> cffi                               cryptography                                   pycparser-2.19.dist-info                      six.py
> [064bit-prompt]> PYTHONPATH=.:${PYTHONPATH} python3 ../code00.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 10 2019, 11:58:48) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 64bit on linux
>
> OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2t-fips  10 Sep 2019
> FIPS_mode(): 0
> FIPS_mode_set(1): 0
> FIPS_mode(): 0
> error:[755413103]:[FIPS routines]:[FIPS_check_incore_fingerprint]:[fingerprint does not match]
>
> Done.
> ```

As seen, I'm pretty much where you are.

### 4. Deeper dive

After long (and some might consider painful) hours of debugging, trials, ...,  I reached to a conclusion. Considering that:

- Tampering with anything from *FOM* (contents of *${FIPSDIR}*), will no loner qualify as ***FIPS* validated**. To be frank, neither does this, as there are specific instructions that when building *FOM*, only a *sys admin* should copy the artifacts in a secure location ...., bla, bla, bla. This seems paranoid to me, but these are the facts. As a remark, back in 2013, when we 1<sup>st</sup> came in contact with *FIPS* (probably to prevent any possible attack (e.g. *MITM*)), the *FOM* sources ***CD*** was shipped from *USA* to *ROU* :)))
- Default *Python* version is statically (again :) ) built, meaning that *${PYTHONCORE}* (the *Python* interpreter) resides in the *python* executable, rather than in a *.so* (*libpython*.so**) that can be linked to (and that the *python* executable does in case of shared builds)
- *Cryptography*'s *_openssl* extension module (*_openssl.abi*.so*) needs symbols from *${PYTHONCORE}* (e.g. *PyLong_FromLong*), but that's *OK* since at the moment it will be loaded into the (*Python*) process (launched from the aforementioned executable), it will find them (this is a common practice on *Nix*)
- **Build step *#3.2.***: the executable (*FPD* - which must run) doesn't find the symbols, so it fails

This is a deadlock (whatever room one constraint leaves, is closed by others), so **IT SIMPLY CAN'T BE DONE !!!** (at least, at this time). **Period!!!** X(

### 5. Alternative

I was going to suggest this as an elegant alternative (including the *OpenSSL* *.so*s (with any (*.so*) client having *rpath* set to "there") in the *.whl*, next to *_openssl.abi3.so* which links to them), but apparently this is the only way (that I've found, at least).

The 1<sup>st</sup> step, is to build a shared *OpenSSL* version (*FOME* will be *libcrypto.so.**).

> ```bash
> [064bit-prompt]> ls
> code00.py  cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
> [064bit-prompt]> export OPENSSL_DIR=/home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/openssl-1.0.2t-fips-2.0.16
> [064bit-prompt]> ldd ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl
>         linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe62faf000)
>         libssl.so.1.0.0 => /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/openssl-1.0.2t-fips-2.0.16/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fe33c06f000)
>         libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /home/cfati/Work/Dev/Tools/openssl-1.0.2t-fips-2.0.16/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fe33bb92000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe33b7c8000)
>         libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe33b5c4000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe33c2e3000)
> [064bit-prompt]>
> [064bit-prompt]> ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl version
> OpenSSL 1.0.2t-fips  10 Sep 2019
> [064bit-prompt]> ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl md5 ./code00.py
> MD5(./code00.py)= eac85e46734260c1bfcceb89d6a3bd32
> [064bit-prompt]> OPENSSL_FIPS=1 ${OPENSSL_DIR}/bin/openssl md5 ./code00.py
> Error setting digest md5
> 139796140275352:error:060A80A3:digital envelope routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips:fips_md.c:180
> ```

After another session of deep diving (lots of failed attempts), I was able to get it working. However, took a lot of actions:

- Manual interventions
- Hacks
- (Lame) workarounds (*gainarii*)

I'm afraid that if I'd put everything here it would well exceed the *30K* *char*s limit ([[SE.Meta]: Knowing Your Limits: What is the maximum length of a question title, post, image and links used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176445/360056)).

However, I published the *.whl* at **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/Cryptography/v2.7](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/Cryptography/v2.7)**. So far it's for *Python 3.5* (*64bit*) only, as it's the default version that comes on *Ubuntu 16*. If you use another (newer) version, just let me know, and I'll get it (maybe build it myself), and build the *.whl* for that version too (I am going to do it anyway).

After replacing the original *.whl* with the one built by me:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build]> ll
> total 2936
> drwxrwxr-x 2 cfati cfati    4096 Oct  9 21:40 .
> drwxrwxr-x 4 cfati cfati    4096 Oct  9 21:28 ..
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 cfati cfati  108067 Oct  9 08:43 asn1crypto-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 cfati cfati  318045 Oct  9 08:43 cffi-1.12.3-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 cfati cfati 2438739 Oct  9 21:40 cryptography-2.7-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 cfati cfati  112066 Oct  9 08:43 pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> -rw-rw-r-- 1 cfati cfati   12099 Oct  9 08:43 six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build]> for f in $(ls *.whl); do unzip ${f} > /dev/null; done
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build]> ls
> asn1crypto                         cffi-1.12.3-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl        cryptography-2.7-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl  pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> asn1crypto-1.0.1.dist-info         cffi-1.12.3.dist-info                          cryptography-2.7.dist-info                    six-1.12.0.dist-info
> asn1crypto-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl  _cffi_backend.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so  pycparser                                     six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> cffi                               cryptography                                   pycparser-2.19.dist-info                      six.py
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q058228435/build]> PYTHONPATH=.:${PYTHONPATH} python3 ../code00.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 10 2019, 11:58:48) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] 64bit on linux
>
> OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2t-fips  10 Sep 2019
> FIPS_mode(): 0
> FIPS_mode_set(1): 1
> FIPS_mode(): 1
> Success !!!
>
> Done.
> ```

Related (more or less) posts:

- [[SO]: Unable to build a working FIPS capable OpenSSL on HP-UX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35664412/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to enable FIPS mode for libcrypto and libssl packaged with Python? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382743/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to implement FIPS_mode() and FIPS_mode_set() in Python 3.6's ssl module? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49494549/4788546)

Comment: Wow, that was a really detailed response. Based on that, I've pretty much accepted the fact that what I wanted to achieve is probably not possible in a easy and straightforward manner. I will go ahead and accept this answer for the bounty. I definitely learned a lot :)

Comment: By the way, really appreciate that you described everything in a way that was super easy to read and understand. Thank you again @CristiFati.

Comment: You're welcome! But it's not clear to me what exactly you want.You mentioned that you wanted to create a static lib.I don't know how would that work given the fact that *Cryptography* embeds *OpenSSL* in a *.so*. And if you create a static lib you'll need to link it into something, and therefore follow *FIPS* link steps. Anyway, did you give the *.whl* a try? Or it's the wrong *Python* version? As I said I'm going to do the same thing for *v3.7* and *v3.6* (*64bit*).

Comment: Forgot to mention: Thank you for the gift!!! But I have a feeling that your "end goal" question is still pending ...