# RHEL8: FIPS Object Module (fipscanister) existing?

Tags: openssl, redhat, fips, rhel8

I am confused by RHEL8. It reports:

```
# openssl
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
OpenSSL> exit
# find / -name fipscanister*.*
```

My system reports to be running a FIPS compliant OpenSSL, but I do not find a FIPS canister on the system ... I inspected the ISO (rhel-8.4-x86_64-dvd.iso), there is in BaseOS/Packages: openssl-devel-1.1.1g-15.el8_3.x86_64.rpm, but also this does not contain a FIPS canister ...

What needs to be done to have a fipscanister lib on the system?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean *fipscanister.o* (the object file where the *FIPS* algorithms are compiled in). You won't find it, as it was linked in *libcrypto.so**.

According to [[OpenSSL]: UserGuide-2.0.pdf - User Guide for the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> Note that except in the most unusual circumstances the FIPS Object Module itself
> (**fipscanister.o**) is not linked directly with application code. ***Instead the FIPS Object Module
> is embedded in the OpenSSL libcrypto library (libcrypto.a/libcrypto.so)*** which is then referenced in the usual way by the application code. That combination is known as a "FIPS capable" OpenSSL
> library and is discussed in more detail in section 2.5.

Check [[SO]: OpenSSL FIPS_mode_set not working in Python cryptography library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58311407/4788546) for (some interesting) details.

Here's some sample output (environment left from [[SO]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670925/4788546)):

> ```py
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> python
> Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) 
> [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>> 
> >>> lcr = ct.CDLL("openssl-1.1.1g/lib/libcrypto.so")  # Load a library
> >>> lcr.FIPS_mode()  # Call a function exported by it (for demo purposes only, not use (like this) in production)
> 0
> ```

Comment: How to know the version of the FIPS Object Module embedded in the OpenSSL libcrypto.so?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I am not aware of that info. But depending on where you got the **FIPS* capable OpenSSL*  version, they should have it documented. Most likely it's 2.0.