# How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, redhat

I'm trying to compile python on RHEL because my current python is using an old 1.0.2k ssl version.

```
(test_env) [brad@reason tlscheck]$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.3
(test_env) [brad@reason tlscheck]$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
(test_env) [brad@reason tlscheck]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

I think the issue is that when I compiled 3.9.3, I had not updated my OpenSSL version.  I have since updated my OpenSSL and need to use it with python.  So I have downloaded the newest python 3.10, but in the make stage I get an error that it will not make with ssl.  I the following message:

```
Following modules built successfully but were removed because they could not be imported:
_hashlib              _ssl                                     


Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires a OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer
```

This is the full log of trying to compile:
https://pastebin.com/36EntpFz

When I use the configure options that @tony-yip mentioned, I get the following in my configure.

```
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /etc/ssl... no
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... no
```

I'm determining my openssl location with:

```
[brad@reason Python-3.10.0]$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/ssl"
```

To configure, I'm using:

```
./configure --with-openssl="/etc/ssl"
```

When I look for ssl.h, I find it in `/usr/include/openssl`.  So I linked this directory to lib in `/etc/ssl`, but it was no help.

```
[brad@reason Python-3.10.0]$ ls -l /etc/ssl
total 40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Jul 16  2020 certs -> ../pki/tls/certs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   412 Oct 12 02:53 ct_log_list.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   412 Oct 12 02:53 ct_log_list.cnf.dist
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20 Oct 18 10:22 lib -> /usr/include/openssl
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 12 02:53 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10909 Oct 12 02:53 openssl.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10909 Oct 12 02:53 openssl.cnf.dist
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 12 02:53 private
[brad@reason Python-3.10.0]$ sudo find / -name ssl.h | grep include
find: ‘/tmp/.mount_jetbraAJFEnl’: Permission denied
/home/brad/Downloads/freerdp-2.0.0-rc4/winpr/include/winpr/ssl.h
/home/brad/Downloads/FreeRDP/winpr/include/winpr/ssl.h
/home/brad/Development/tlscheck/openssl-1.1.1l/include/openssl/ssl.h
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/23e6f3c164ec8939352891c99393669df4ed6e66da1e04ce84616073f08c6051/diff/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/18.08/c8075e929daaffcbe5c78c9e87c0f0463d75e90d2b59c92355fa486e79c7d0e3/files/include/nss/ssl.h
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/18.08/c8075e929daaffcbe5c78c9e87c0f0463d75e90d2b59c92355fa486e79c7d0e3/files/include/openssl/ssl.h
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

This may be extraneous information, but my libssl.so is here:

```
[brad@reason Python-3.10.0]$ ls /usr/lib64 | grep ssl
libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5
libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.1.9
libssl3.so
libssl.so
libssl.so.10
libssl.so.1.0.2k
openssl
```

Any thoughts on why make isn't able to include ssl, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320993/how-to-enable-fips-mode-for-libcrypto-and-libssl-packaged-with-python/49382743#49382743

Answer (score 21):

This was very helpful, thanks!  What kicked me onto this was the inability to run/update `pip` in a venv, so there wasn't much of an alternative to figuring out how to get OpenSSL to work.

As of this week (21 December 2021), in my environment (`CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`), I was able to shortcut parts of this.

From EPEL, installing `openssl11`, (yes, also `openssl11-devel`); to set up Python 3.10 properly I needed to create that "OpenSSL Directory" which I did by:

```
mkdir /usr/local/openssl11
```

Then setting symlinks for the (newly-installed) requirements:

```
cd /usr/local/openssl11
ln -s /usr/lib64/openssl11 lib
ln -s /usr/include/openssl11 include
```

And, finally, feeding this location to the `configure` script:

```
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl11
```

Thanks for the really helpful explanations of how and why this was all necessary. Hope this helps others...

Comment: This was the only way I could get pip to work (so that I could get TurboGears working.).

Comment: This method helped me too

Comment: Thanks man! you saved my day! tested everything but this does the trick!

Comment: This worked for me, too, building python3.10 on RHEL 7.9. Thank you!

Comment: worked for centos 7,  simplest solution, thank you

Answer (score 18):

Had a very similar problem, with openssl not working  and giving the same errors with python 3.10 on centos 7.
Download openssl unpack then go to that directory

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/custom-openssl --openssldir=/etc/ssl
make -j1 depend
make -j8
make install_sw
```

Then go to the python source unpack it and run in the directory

```
./configure -C --with-openssl=/usr/local/custom-openssl --with-openssl-rpath=auto --prefix=/usr/local/python-3.version
make -j8
make altinstall
```

See also Custom OpenSSL on https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html.

Comment: This was it for me, I have been trying to fix this for days

Comment: When I used this `--with-openssl-rpath=auto`, to my surprise it actually added a RUNPATH in the .so, not an rpath. Was no problem for me, but they do behave differently, so that's something to watch out for if you care about the differences.

Answer (score 6):

As the output suggest, you need to point to openssl11.
The easiest way I found to do it is to change the `configure` file in the python 3.10 source code directory:

```
$ sed -i 's/PKG_CONFIG openssl /PKG_CONFIG openssl11 /g' configure
$ sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
.
.
checking whether compiling and linking against OpenSSL works... yes
.
```

Then you can do as @CristiFati suggested in order  to check before installing that it is configured properly:

```
$ ./python -c "import sys, ssl; print(\"{:s}\n{:s}\".format(sys.version, ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))"
3.10.0 (default, Nov 29 2021, 17:48:34) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13)]
OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Intro

Some references that might be (more or less) useful:

- [[SO]: How to enable FIPS mode for libcrypto and libssl packaged with Python? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382743/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546) (even if it's for *Win*, it has some good points that apply to *Nix* as well)
- [[SO]: OpenSSL FIPS_mode_set not working in Python cryptography library (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58311407/4788546)
- [[SO]: ./python: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50528187/4788546)
- [[SO]: OpenSSL 3.0.8: FIPS functionality not working with libcrypto library in custom path (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75917800/4788546)

Working on a *CentOS 7* image from [Docker Hub](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-hub) (as it's closest to *RHEL 7* (that you're having))

> ```bash
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> uname -a
> Linux cfati-5510-0 5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 09:06:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> cat /etc/redhat-release 
> CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> 
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> rpm -qa | grep openssl
> openssl-libs-1.0.2k-22.el7_9.x86_64
> openssl-1.0.2k-22.el7_9.x86_64
> openssl-devel-1.0.2k-22.el7_9.x86_64
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> 
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> openssl version
> OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> which openssl
> /usr/bin/openssl
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> ldd /usr/bin/openssl
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe101b7000)
>     libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f9483b8a000)
>     libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f948393d000)
>     libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f9483654000)
>     libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f9483450000)
>     libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f948321d000)
>     libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f9482dba000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9482bb6000)
>     libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f94829a0000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f94825d2000)
>     libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f94823c2000)
>     libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f94821be000)
>     libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f9481fa4000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9481d88000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9483dfc000)
>     libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9481b61000)
>     libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f94818ff000)
> ```

### 2. *OpenSSL* considerations

- As seen (also present in previous snippet), *CentOS 7* (and I think *RHEL 7* as well) comes with *OpenSSL 1.0.2**. Since *OpenSSL 1.1.1** is a minor (but kind of major) release, they are ***not*** (*API* / *ABI*) compatible, and therefore not interchangeable
- *v1.0.2** is ***de facto*** (main) version for *CentOS 7* (*RHEL 7* too), everything is built against it, changing it would break things. But it is possible to install newer versions (I used the *EPEL* (more on [[RedHat]: What's EPEL, and how do I use it?](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/whats-epel-and-how-do-i-use-it)) *repo* ([[Pkgs.CentOS]: EPEL x86_64](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64)) which provides ***v1.1.1g***). But they will only **work around the main version**. For example, almost every (important) file name in the newer version has a suffix at the end (the *.exe* is called ***openssl11***) in order to avoid name clashes with main version

  - Since *v1.1.1g* installs in the (pretty much) same location as the main version (with changed names), it won't get picked up (by default) by any build system. So I had to unpack the *rpm*s (via *RPM2Cpio*) in a custom *dir*
  - Not sure how you got *v1.1.1**l*** - probably built it yourself (or found it somewhere), so some of the next steps might not be required. 
    As a side note, I built (an in house modified) *OpenSSL* version on a variety of *OS*es / *CPU* architecutes (*RHEL 7* included) many times, but since the *rpm*s were available, I didn't bother to do it again
- Even if *openssl11* (and its dependent *openssl11-libs*) is "up and running", ***openssl11-devel* is also required** by the *Python* build

> ```bash
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> mkdir -p openssl-1.1.1g && cd openssl-1.1.1g
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ls
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> for g in /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/packages/openssl11-libs-1.1.1g-3.el7.x86_64.rpm /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/packages/openssl11-1.1.1g-3.el7.x86_64.rpm /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/packages/openssl11-devel-1.1.1g-3.el7.x86_64.rpm; do rpm2cpio ${g} | cpio -idm; done
> 7292 blocks
> 2123 blocks
> 8352 blocks
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ls
> etc  usr
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ll ./usr/bin/
> total 637
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    610 Mar 29  2021 make-dummy-cert
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 644424 Mar 29  2021 openssl11
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    725 Mar 29  2021 renew-dummy-cert
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ./usr/bin/openssl11 
> ./usr/bin/openssl11: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ll ./usr/lib64/
> total 3605
> drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Oct 21 23:55 engines-1.1
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Oct 21 23:55 libcrypto.so.1.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.1.1g
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3082216 Mar 29  2021 libcrypto.so.1.1.1g
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 21 23:55 libssl.so.1.1 -> libssl.so.1.1.1g
> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  603568 Mar 29  2021 libssl.so.1.1.1g
> drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Oct 21 23:55 openssl11
> drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       0 Oct 21 23:55 pkgconfig
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ldd ./usr/bin/openssl11 
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffca03f5000)
>     libssl.so.1.1 => not found
>     libcrypto.so.1.1 => not found
>     libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3a61e56000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3a61c52000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3a61a36000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a61668000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3a6206c000)
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> # Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./usr/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ldd ./usr/bin/openssl11
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdf7fce000)
>     libssl.so.1.1 => ./usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fe00f7a4000)
>     libcrypto.so.1.1 => ./usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fe00f2c1000)
>     libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fe00f0ab000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe00eea7000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe00ec8b000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe00e8bd000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe00fa34000)
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./usr/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ./usr/bin/openssl11 version
> OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./usr/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ./usr/bin/openssl11 version -d
> OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
> ```

So, here's a working *OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS* version.

### 3. *Python* build

*OpenSSL* is fine from its *PoV*, but it needs some "small" adjustments in order for *Python* build to pick it up:

- *include* and *lib* *dir*s must have the same parent (they reside lower in the *dir* tree, *symlink* them in the *OpenSSL* root *dir*)
- Libraries with the ***11* suffix** (from earlier) must also be present, *symlink* them as well

> ```bash
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> # OpenSSL working. Prepare for Python build.
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> # "include" and "lib" dirs must be at the same level - symlink them
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ln -s ./usr/include/openssl11 ./include
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ln -s ./usr/lib64/openssl11 ./lib
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ls . ./lib
> .:
> etc  include  lib  usr
>
> ./lib:
> libcrypto.so  libssl.so
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> # "lib" dir must also contain $(LIBNAME).1.1 besides what's already in there ($(LIBNAME))
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ln -s libcrypto.so ./lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ln -s libssl.so ./lib/libssl.so.1.1
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/openssl-1.1.1g]> ls ./lib
> libcrypto.so  libcrypto.so.1.1  libssl.so  libssl.so.1.1
> ```

*Python* (*configure* and *make*):

> ```bash
> root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> tar -zxf Python-3.10.0.tgz 
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286]> cd Python-3.10.0
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> ./configure --with-openssl=$(pwd)/../openssl-1.1.1g --with-openssl-rpath=auto --prefix=$(pwd)/../python-3.10>../cfg.txt 2>&1
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> echo $?
> 0
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/../openssl-1.1.1g/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} make -j8>../mk.txt 2>&1
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> echo $?
> 0
> ```

### 4. Test

Build was successful. 
Quick tests (**without `make install`**):

> ```bash
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> # Quick test
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> # --------------------------------
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> ./python -c "import sys, ssl; print(\"{:s}\n{:s}\".format(sys.version, ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))"
> 3.10.0 (default, Oct 22 2021, 01:12:00) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
> OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> # --------------------------------
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> # As opposed to "regular" Python
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> python -c "import sys, ssl; print(\"{:s}\n{:s}\".format(sys.version, ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION))"
> 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) 
> [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
> OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
>
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> ./python -c "import ssl; print(ssl._ssl)"
> <module '_ssl' from '/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/_ssl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> ldd /work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/_ssl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffef6b7b000)
>     libssl.so.1.1 => /work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0/../openssl-1.1.1g/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f0ab9745000)
>     libcrypto.so.1.1 => /work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0/../openssl-1.1.1g/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f0ab9262000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0ab9046000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0ab8c78000)
>     libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0ab8a62000)
>     libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0ab885e000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0ab9c05000)
> [root@cfati-5510-0:/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0]> readelf -d /work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10/_ssl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep ssl
>  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
>  0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/work/q069539286/Python-3.10.0/../openssl-1.1.1g/lib]
> ```

Comment: What did you get for `readelf -d _ssl.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` ?

Comment: @wim: unfortunately I don't have container and image anymore (on *Docker Desktop* (*Win*)).  There's a small chance that I could still have it on my *Linux* system (dual-boot) next time I'll work on it will check. But anyway since it worked with no *LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH*, I'm expecting it to have *DT\_RUNPATH* (*DT\_RPATH*) flag set (also because of `--with-openssl-rpath=auto`).

Comment: I got the RUNPATH which surprised me because the configure flag suggests its putting RPATH. And RPATH is what I wanted, not RUNPATH, because I _don't_ want env LD_LIBRARY_PATH to have any say here.

Comment: I studied some years ago this topic. In many cases I see them used interchangeably. Anyway, I think that option translates to linker's *-rpath*.

Comment: @wim: I found the container (on my other dual boot *OS*). It's indeed *DT\_RUNPATH* (but *DT\_RPATH* is deprecated). Added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python will use the bundled ssl (witch is outdated sometimes). In order to then use OpenSSL, add flag for OpenSSL when running ./configure. For detail, run `./configure --help` for more options.

```
  --with-openssl=DIR      root of the OpenSSL directory
  --with-openssl-rpath=[DIR|auto|no]
                          Set runtime library directory (rpath) for OpenSSL
                          libraries, no (default): don't set rpath, auto:
                          auto-detect rpath from --with-openssl and
                          pkg-config, DIR: set an explicit rpath
  --with-ssl-default-suites=[python|openssl|STRING]
                          override default cipher suites string, python: use
                          Python's preferred selection (default), openssl:
                          leave OpenSSL's defaults untouched, STRING: use a
                          custom string, python and STRING also set TLS 1.2 as
                          minimum TLS version
```

Comment: *Python* will **not** "*use it own bundled ssl suite*" (there's no such thing). It will rely on the default *OpenSSL* installation (if any).