# Access OpenSSL FIPS APIs from python ctypes not working

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, ctypes, fips

Python: 3.9.16
OpenSSL: 3.0.8

> fips_ccode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/provider.h>
#include "openssl/md5.h"

int main(void)
{
        OSSL_PROVIDER* fips;
        OSSL_PROVIDER* base;

        const char* default_search_path = "/tmp/fips_files/";
        OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path(NULL, default_search_path);
        int load_config = OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(NULL, "/tmp/fips_files/openssl.cnf") ;
        printf("loading config:%d\n", load_config);
   
        fips = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "fips");
        printf("value:%x\n",fips);

        printf("Success to load FIPS provider\n");

        base = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "base");

        printf("Success to load base provider\n");
}
```

> fips_python.py

```
import ctypes
import os
import ssl
import ssl, os
import hashlib

BASEDIR="/tmp/"
FILENAME="libcrypto.so.3"

def get_crypto_lib_path():
    return os.path.join(BASEDIR, FILENAME)


crypto_context = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(BASEDIR, get_crypto_lib_path()))
crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p]
crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.restype = ctypes.c_char
crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path(None, "/tmp/fips_files/")


crypto_context.OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p]
crypto_context.OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.restype = ctypes.c_int
load_config = crypto_context.OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(None, "/tmp/fips_files/openssl.cnf")
print("load config:", load_config)

crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_load.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p]
crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_load.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p
base_load = crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, "base")
print("base load ret value:", base_load)

crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_load.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p]
crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_load.restype = ctypes.c_wchar_p
fips_load = crypto_context.OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, "fips")
print("fips load ret value:", fips_load)
```

Here I am seeing issue in loading the provider "fips" and "base" using "OSSL_PROVIDER_load" function in python using ctypes.
What is the proper way to load the c function here? are the arguments type used correct?

Comment: Define "*not working*". Post an expected and actual output: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For the library location problem, ask a new question referencing this one, describing the problem (just like in your deleted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are a bunch of errors in the code:

1. *LibCrypto*'s path is incorrectly computed (*BASEDIR* is prepended twice)
2. You want to use *OpenSSL v**3.0*** functionality, but *LibCrypto*'s name suggests *v**1.1***. There's a big difference between the 2.
   Obviously (unless *libcrypto.so.1.1* is a misleadingly named *SymLink*), the functions will not be present, and therefore fail to load
3. *Python* functions prototypes differ from the *C* ones which an be found at:

   - [[OpenSSL]: OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.html)
   - [[OpenSSL]: OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.html)

   That yields ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for more details
4. There are others (like not checking function return codes), but those are just lightweights compared to the previous ones

I prepared a small example that fixes the 3<sup>rd</sup> point.

*code00.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import os
import sys


PATH_LIBCRYPTO = "../q069539286/docker/openssl-1.1.1g/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1.1g"
PATH_LIBCRYPTO = "/tmp/libcrypto.so.1.1"
PATH_CFG = b"/tmp/fips_files/"

# @TODO - cfati: Use my paths
PATH_OSSL3_BASE = "/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.10"
PATH_LIBCRYPTO = os.path.join(PATH_OSSL3_BASE, "lib", "libcrypto.so.3")
PATH_CFG = os.path.join(PATH_OSSL3_BASE.encode(), b"ssl")

POSSL_LIB_CTX = cts.c_void_p
POSSL_PROVIDER = cts.c_void_p


def main(*argv):
    libcrypto = cts.CDLL(PATH_LIBCRYPTO)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path = libcrypto.OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.restype = cts.c_int
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config = libcrypto.OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.restype = cts.c_int
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load = libcrypto.OSSL_PROVIDER_load
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load.restype = POSSL_PROVIDER

    res = OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path(None, PATH_CFG)
    if res == 0:
        print("OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path error")
        return 1
    res = OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(None, os.path.join(PATH_CFG, b"openssl.cnf"))
    if res == 0:
        print("OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config error")
        return 1
    base_provider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, b"base")
    fips_provider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, b"fips")

    print(f"Base: {base_provider}\nFIPS: {fips_provider}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q075889485]> python ./code00.py 
> Python 3.8.18 (default, Aug 25 2023, 13:20:30) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Base: 17667472
> FIPS: None
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- The above output:

  - Works, but *FIPS* is not enabled in the default config
  - Used [[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/OpenSSL](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/OpenSSL)
- Although *CTypes* is a nice bridge between *Python* and *C* (I personally like it), it requires writing a lot of boilerplate code. There could be better alternatives for your case that allow achieving the desired functionality. You might research some *OpenSSL* wrappers for *Python* like:

  - [[PyPI]: pyOpenSSL](https://pypi.org/project/pyOpenSSL)
  - [[PyPI]: cryptography](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography)
- Might also want to check:

  - [[SO]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670925/4788546)
  - [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546)
  - Your follow-up question: [[SO]: OpenSSL 3.0.8: FIPS functionality not working with libcrypto library in custom path (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75917800/4788546) :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is very helpful.I corrected my mistakes. I enabled FIPS using your script but 
FIPS functionality is not working when I use a custom libcrypto path but works if I use the default path.
custom path:/tmp/fips_files/libcrypto.so.3
default path: usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.3