# OpenSSL 3.0.8: FIPS functionality not working with libcrypto library in custom path

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, md5, fips

OpenSSL: 3.0.8
Python: 3.9.16

I enabled FIPS using below script but FIPS functionality is not working when I use custom libcrypto path but working fine if I use default path.
custom path:/tmp/fips_files/libcrypto.so.3
default path: usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys,hashlib


#PATH_LIBCRYPTO = "/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.3"
PATH_LIBCRYPTO = "/tmp/fips_files/libcrypto.so.3"

POSSL_LIB_CTX = cts.c_void_p
POSSL_PROVIDER = cts.c_void_p


def main(*argv):
    libcrypto = cts.CDLL(PATH_LIBCRYPTO)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path = libcrypto.OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.restype = cts.c_int

    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config = libcrypto.OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.restype = cts.c_int

    OSSL_PROVIDER_load = libcrypto.OSSL_PROVIDER_load
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load.restype = POSSL_PROVIDER

    res = OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path(None, b"/tmp/fips_files/")
    if res == 0:
        print("OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path error")
        return 1
    res = OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(None, b"/tmp/fips_files/openssl.cnf")
    if res == 0:
        print("OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config error")
        return 1
    base_provider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, b"base")
    fips_provider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, b"fips")
    print(base_provider, fips_provider)


    libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled.argtypes = [cts.c_void_p]
    libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled.restype = cts.c_int
    fips_status = libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(None)
    print("fips status before:",fips_status)

    libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_enable_fips.argtypes = [cts.c_void_p, cts.c_int]
    libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_enable_fips.restype = cts.c_int
    ret_status = libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(None, 1)
    print ("return :", ret_status)


    fips_status = libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(None)
    print("fips status after :",fips_status)

    print(hashlib.sha1("test_str".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
    print(hashlib.md5("test_str".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(rc)
```

With cutom libcrypto path FIPS not WORKING:
PATH_LIBCRYPTO = "/tmp/fips_files/libcrypto.so.3"

```
root@gssd-ubuntu184:~/Pradeep/FIPS# python new_load_conf_file.py fips base
Python 3.9.16 (main, Feb 20 2023, 12:42:50) [Clang 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)] 064bit on linux

94512782592400 94512782460240
fips status before: 1
return : 1
fips status after : 1
f9a90e7c1ff51236191623b84267d110c617118a
74e710825309d622d0b920390ef03edf
```

With default libcrypto path FIPS WORKING:
PATH_LIBCRYPTO = "/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.3"

```
root@gssd-ubuntu184:~/Pradeep/FIPS# python new_load_conf_file.py fips base
Python 3.9.16 (main, Feb 20 2023, 12:42:50) [Clang 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)] 064bit on linux

94480037288352 94480037156144
fips status before: 1
return : 1
fips status after : 1
f9a90e7c1ff51236191623b84267d110c617118a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Pradeep/FIPS/new_load_conf_file.py", line 63, in <module>
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "/root/Pradeep/FIPS/new_load_conf_file.py", line 56, in main
    print(hashlib.md5("test_str".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
ValueError: [digital envelope routines] unsupported
```

Could you please help me in making FIPS work using libs in the custom path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: hashlib - Secure hashes and message digests](https://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib).

I want to start with a note: it **is possible** to have multiple instances of the "same" library loaded in a process, as shown in [[SO]: Independent CDLL Library Instances with Ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257116/4788546).

Check [[SO]: How to enable FIPS mode for libcrypto and libssl packaged with Python? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382743/4788546).
It's a **duplicate** of the referenced (closed) question at the end (*Update #0* section).

What happens:

- Default *LibCrypto* (if found) is loaded by `import hashlib`
- You load "your own" *LibCrypto* version, where you set *FIPS* mode on
- *HashLib* on the other hand, is still using the default instance (where *FIPS* is not enabled)

I tested with *OpenSSL 3.0.8*.

**Output** - Preliminary (note that I'll be reusing this console):

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q075913071]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> # Test OpenSSL
> [064bit prompt]> /usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/bin/openssl md5 ./code00.py
> FATAL: Startup failure (dev note: apps_startup()) for /usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/bin/openssl
> 80E2A959297F0000:error:80000002:system library:process_include:No such file or directory:crypto/conf/conf_def.c:805:calling stat(fipsmodule.cnf)
> 80E2A959297F0000:error:07800069:common libcrypto routines:provider_conf_load:provider section error:crypto/provider_conf.c:156:section=fips_sect not found
> 80E2A959297F0000:error:0700006D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error:crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:270:module=providers, value=provider_sect retcode=-1
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> # Local configuration stuff
> [064bit prompt]> OPENSSL_CONF_INCLUDE=/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/ssl /usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/bin/openssl md5 ./code00.py
> Error setting digest
> 80123BCEDC7F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:373:Global default library context, Algorithm (MD5 : 102), Properties ()
> 80123BCEDC7F0000:error:03000086:digital envelope routines:evp_md_init_internal:initialization error:crypto/evp/digest.c:254:
> ```

Check [[GitHub]: openssl/openssl - openssl.cnf failed to load fispmodules.cnf if use without full path in 3.0.1 (@CristiFati's comment)](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/17704#issuecomment-1493317934) for details regarding *OPENSSL_CONF_INCLUDE*.
Since *OpenSSL* build (**with *FIPS* support**) is valid, moving to *Python* stuff. Here's an updated version of your code:

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import hashlib
import os
import sys


#LIBCRYPTO = "/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.3"
CUSTOM_PATH = "/tmp/fips_files"
LIBCRYPTO = os.path.join(CUSTOM_PATH, "libcrypto.so.3")

CUSTOM_PATH = "/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8"  # @TODO - cfati: Custom build path
LIBCRYPTO = os.path.join(CUSTOM_PATH, "lib", "libcrypto.so")  # @TODO - cfati: Custom build lib path

POSSL_LIB_CTX = cts.c_void_p
POSSL_PROVIDER = cts.c_void_p


def main(*argv):
    libcrypto = cts.CDLL(LIBCRYPTO)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path = libcrypto.OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path.restype = cts.c_int

    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config = libcrypto.OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config.restype = cts.c_int

    OSSL_PROVIDER_load = libcrypto.OSSL_PROVIDER_load
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_char_p)
    OSSL_PROVIDER_load.restype = POSSL_PROVIDER

    EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled = libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled
    EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX,)
    EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled.restype = cts.c_int

    EVP_default_properties_enable_fips = libcrypto.EVP_default_properties_enable_fips
    EVP_default_properties_enable_fips.argtypes = (POSSL_LIB_CTX, cts.c_int)
    EVP_default_properties_enable_fips.restype = cts.c_int

    provider_search_path = CUSTOM_PATH.encode()
    provider_search_path = os.path.join(CUSTOM_PATH, "lib", "ossl-modules").encode()  # @TODO - cfati: Custom mod location

    res = OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path(None, provider_search_path)
    if res == 0:
        print("OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path error")
        return 1
    

    cfg_search_path = provider_search_path
    cfg_search_path = os.path.join(CUSTOM_PATH, "ssl").encode()  # @TODO - cfati: Custom cfg location
    res = OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config(None, os.path.join(cfg_search_path, b"openssl.cnf"))
    if res == 0:
        print("OSSL_LIB_CTX_load_config error")
        return 1
    base_provider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, b"base")
    fips_provider = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(None, b"fips")
    print(base_provider, fips_provider)


    fips_status = EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(None)
    print("EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: {:d}".format(fips_status))

    res = EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(None, 1)
    print ("EVP_default_properties_enable_fips: {:d}".format(res))


    fips_status = EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(None)
    print("EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: {:d}".format(fips_status))

    print("HL mod: {:}".format(getattr(hashlib, "_hashlib", None)))
    print("SHA1: {:s}".format(hashlib.sha1("test_str".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()))
    print("MD5: {:s}".format(hashlib.md5("test_str".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> # Attempt #0.
> [064bit prompt]> OPENSSL_CONF_INCLUDE=/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/ssl python3.9 ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> 20919264 20902112
> EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: 0
> EVP_default_properties_enable_fips: 1
> EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: 1
> HL mod: <module '_hashlib' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
> SHA1: f9a90e7c1ff51236191623b84267d110c617118a
> MD5: 74e710825309d622d0b920390ef03edf
>
> Done.
>
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> # Attempt #1.
> [064bit prompt]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/lib OPENSSL_CONF_INCLUDE=/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/ssl python3.9 ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> 36180960 36163808
> EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: 0
> EVP_default_properties_enable_fips: 1
> EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: 1
> HL mod: <module '_hashlib' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
> SHA1: f9a90e7c1ff51236191623b84267d110c617118a
> MD5: 74e710825309d622d0b920390ef03edf
>
> Done.
>
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ldd /usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>         linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe72fe9000)
>         libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ff3fb0f9000)
>         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff3faf07000)
>         libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff3faf01000)
>         libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff3faede000)
>         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff3fb405000)
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> # Attempt #2.
> [064bit prompt]> ln -s /usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/lib/libcrypto.so ./libcrypto.so.1.1
> [064bit prompt]> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/lib OPENSSL_CONF_INCLUDE=/usr/local/pc064/openssl/openssl/3.0.8/ssl python3.9 ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> 43861088 43843936
> EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: 0
> EVP_default_properties_enable_fips: 1
> EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled: 1
> HL mod: None
> SHA1: f9a90e7c1ff51236191623b84267d110c617118a
> MD5: 74e710825309d622d0b920390ef03edf
>
> Done.
> ```

Since (default) *Python*'s *HashLib* is built with *OpenSSL 1.1.**, and there's a big *API* / *ABI* difference between that and *v3.**, it doesn't work (as seen, in the 3<sup>rd</sup> attempt I tried a (lame) workaround (*gainarie*), but *HashLib* bindings to *OpenSSL* failed to load, and default implementations were used).
In order to get past this, you need to build *Python* with *OpenSSL 3.** (not sure if it works *OOTB*). Check [[SO]: How to compile python3 on RHEL with SSL? SSL cannot be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69670925/4788546) for details (although versions differ).

Anyway, setting ***LD_LIBRARY_PATH*** should do the trick. In your case, something like:

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/fips_files:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} python ./code00.py
```

As I stated in your other question ([[SO]: Access OpenSSL FIPS APIs from python ctypes not working (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75890880/4788546)), things might be easier if using some specialized *Python* modules (*OpenSSL* wrappers).